# Scaffolding SQL Server Views with Entity Framework 7 in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a database which holds views, and in my old pre-Core app, I relied on it heavily to retrieve information.

However, with EF 7 - using `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=myServerName; Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName; Integrated Security=True" EntityFramework.SqlServer` only scaffolds/allows me to use **tables**. Is there anyway I can access my view data with EF 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. EF Core does not support views (yet). See this issue on EF Core: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1679

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. Good to know that it's being worked on.

Comment: but EF Core itself supports views right - I just have to manually create them